# IdeaVim in PhpStorm - Sidebar "Notches" for Search Instances?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, phpstorm, ideavim

If you do a standard PhpStorm/IntelliJ search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, you will see instances represented by yellow "notches" on the right hand side scroll bar:

[image: PhpStorm Find Shows Each Search Instance in Scrollbar Area]

but when I do the same search using IdeaVim's search <kbd>/</kbd>, I don't get the yellow notches:

[image: IdeaVim doesnt show notches]

## Does anyone know how to get the sidebar notches to show using Vim's traditional search?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To be honest, not sure that there is an option for this.

However, it sounds like a nice feature request:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/newIssue?project=VIM&c=Type%20Feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the *Search Results | Text search result* colour option has the *Error stripe mark* value checked. IdeaVim uses this to show the stripe on the scroll bar, and doesn't show anything on the scroll bar if it's unchecked.

[image: Options showing the text search results value]

However, the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> find results will "fall back" to creating error stripes with the background colour.

I've raised an issue ([VIM-1773](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1773)) to get the same behaviour in IdeaVim.

Comment: Thank you citizenmatt, this worked, much appreciated!